# Vuex store only keeps one component updated, not both

Tags: vue.js, vuex

So I have a Vuex store with a few variables, it looks something like this:

```
var dataStore = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        consumer_id: undefined,
        some_other_data: 0
    },
    mutations: {
        update: function(type, payload) {
            state = Object.assign(type, payload);
        }
    }
});
```

And I have two components, both of which are top level Vue components. However `MultiSim` surrounds `Sim`. They both use the following method to access `consumer_id`:

```
consumer_id: {
    get: function () {
        return this.$store.state.consumer_id;
    },
    set: function (value) {
        this.$store.commit('update', {consumer_id: value});
    }
},
```

The issue is that while changes to `consumer_id` are propagated to `Sim`, `MultiSim` only ever sees `undefined` (the default value). `MultiSim` changes `consumer_id`, and this is captured correctly by all three components, but if `Sim` changes, `MultiSim` does not update.

For example:

- `MultiSim` sets `consumer_id = 10`.
- `[MultiSim: 10, Sim: 10, Store: 10]`
- `Sim` sets `consumer_id = 5`.
- `[MultiSim: 10, Sim: 5, Store: 5]`

Can anyone see where I might have gone wrong? Is there a way to force an update to all components?

**Edit:**

So I've found a solution, but it's more of a hack than anything:

- `MultiSim` sets `consumer_id = 10`.
- `[MultiSim: 10, Sim: 10, Store: 10]`
- `Sim` sets `consumer_id = 5`.
- `[MultiSim: this.$store.state.consumer_id /* 5 */, Sim: 5, Store: 5]

Essentially, the computed method of `MultiSim` is not updating, even though it can access the actual stored value just fine.

Comment: Your mutation looks wrong. `state` does not appear like it would be defined (in your case, the state is `type`). Moreover, you can't replace the entire state without `replaceState` IIRC.

Comment: I've tried using `Vue.set(profitSimulatorStore.$store.state, k, payload[k]);`, but I'm getting undefined errors. Do you have an example of `Vue.set` syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of your properties on state are initialized when you create the store, you could send a generic payload to your update mutation using an approach like this:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    consumer_id: undefined,
    some_other_data: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    update: function(state, payload) {
      for ([key, value] of Object.entries(payload))
        state[key] = value
    }
  }
})
```

This will allow your `update` mutation to be generic and set the properties on state.

Here is an example.

```js
console.clear()

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    consumer_id: undefined,
    some_other_data: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    update: function(state, payload) {
      for ([key, value] of Object.entries(payload))
        state[key] = value
    }
  }
})

const Sim = {
  template: `
<div>
Sim <input v-model="consumer_id"> {{consumer_id}}
</div>
`,
  computed:{
    consumer_id: {
      get: function () {
        return this.$store.state.consumer_id;
      },
      set: function (value) {
        this.$store.commit('update', {consumer_id: value});
      }
    },    
  }
}

const MultiSim = {
  template: `
    <div>
      MultiSim <input v-model="consumer_id"> {{consumer_id}}
    </div>
    `,
  computed:{
    consumer_id: {
      get: function () {
        return this.$store.state.consumer_id;
      },
      set: function (value) {
        this.$store.commit('update', {consumer_id: value});
      }
    },    
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  components: {Sim, MultiSim}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <sim></sim>
  <multi-sim></multi-sim>
</div>
```

If the properties are *not* initialized on the state when the store is created, then you will need to use Vue.set.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
    update: function(state, payload) {
      for ([key, value] of Object.entries(payload))
        Vue.set(state, key, value)
    }
  }
})
```

Also, both of these presume that you are creating the payload in every case like you do in your computed set.

Note: Object.entries is not supported in IE, so you may need to resort to Object.keys instead.

Comment: I'm afraid both methods resulted in the same outcome as my original method.

Comment: @Darkstarone Need more code to replicate then. It works in the above example.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try and see if I can make a small example where it fails - the code itself is a few thousand lines, so no point having you try and debug it all! Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @Darkstarone sounds good; ping me when you get something together; I'm interested in the solution.

Comment: I've found a partial solution (see the edit), I can access `consumer_id` via `this.$store.state.consumer_id` to get the correct value, but the computed method doesn't work correctly. Wasn't able to replicate with a small example I'm afraid, toy examples all work fine (as does every other component in the live code!)